# How to fix list index out of range in class_names to draw classification tree

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have A problem that says List index out of range to make a classification tree

How to fix

```
export_graphviz(model_tree_smote, out_file=dot_data,
                filled=True, rounded=True,
                special_characters=True, feature_names = columns, class_names=['0.0', '1.0'])
graph = pydotplus.graph_from_dot_data(dot_data.getvalue())
graph.write_png('classification.png')
Image(graph.creat_png())
```

i get this error

```
    IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-69-40154f7d5762> in <module>()
      7 export_graphviz(model_tree_smote, out_file=dot_data,
      8                 filled=True, rounded=True,
----> 9                 special_characters=True, feature_names = columns, class_names=['0.0', '1.0'])
     10 graph = pydotplus.graph_from_dot_data(dot_data.getvalue())
     11 graph.write_png('classification.png')

10 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sklearn/tree/_export.py in node_to_str(self, tree, node_id, criterion)
    335                 node_string += 'class = '
    336             if self.class_names is not True:
--> 337                 class_name = self.class_names[np.argmax(value)]
    338             else:
    339                 class_name = "y%s%s%s" % (characters[1],

IndexError: list index out of range
```

so i can't print the tree because this error, please help me to clear the problem

Answer (score 0):

The class names should have names of each of the target classes in ascending numerical order. Only relevant for classification and not supported for multi-output.

You haven't shared a snippet of your target variable but check the unique values your target variable column and ensure that the number of **class_names** is equal to the number of your target variables unique values. For example, if your target variable is number of months (12), ensure the number of class names is twelve i.e:

```
class_names = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12']
```

or

```
class_names=['Jan','Feb','Mar','April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Sep','Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
```

Your code should work.